# Haskell Pattern Matching for consecutive list elements

Tags: haskell, recursion, duplicates, pattern-matching, counting

I want to check if the next element in a list is the same as the previous element and increase count using a recursive function and pattern matching in Haskell, how can I do this?
I was thinking of something along the lines of:

```
mrn [] = 0
mrn [x] = 1
mrn (x:xs) 
  |(x == mrn xs) = --what do I increment here? 
  otherwise --what here?
```

If the next element is not the same, I want to reset the count and also store the previous count somewhere else

Answer (score 3):

We do not store our data anywhere else but in the function's output, or in its arguments, updating them from one call to another, because the data in Haskell are immutable -- if `x = 42`, then it *is* 42. It can't be changed.

This means using an initial value of `0` for the `count` argument. It will have to be used by an inner "worker" function defined inside our function, so as to not pollute the global space with irrelevant implementational details.

And to match two consecutive  elements we use `(x:y:xs)` pattern:

```
countDups :: [a] -> Integer
countDups xs  =  go xs 0
   where
   go []  count = count
   go [x] count = count
   go (x:y:xs) count
      | your test = go (y:xs) (count+1)
      | otherwise = go (y:xs) count
```

You will need to do the necessary corrections so that it does what you want, changing the tests in the guards appropriately.

The above will count all the duplications in the list. If you wanted something else, namely, to get the *list* of all consecutive counts, then you will need to have your function *create that list*:

```
dupCounts :: [a] -> [Integer]
dupCounts xs  =  go xs 0 False
   where
   go []  count previousIsSame = [count]
   go [x] count previousIsSame = [count]
   go (x:y:xs) count previousIsSame 
      | your test = go (y:xs) (count+1) ....
      | otherwise = x : go (y:xs) 0 ....
```

Completing / changing / the code should be straightforward, hopefully.